# Why Python dataframe to sql does not work

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy, sql-insert

I have a pandas dataframe and am trying to add it to a SQL table on a SQL server. I made the connection to the SQL server with sqlalchemy. I try it with `df.to_sql()`. But I get an error message that I don't have permission to create a table. But the table already exists and no new one should be created. I have `if_exists='append'`. But I get the same error message. Why does it want to create a table?

`engine = create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{pw}@{server_name}/{database_name}?driver=SQL+Server')`

`df.to_sql('TableName', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)`

Comment: do you have write permissions on the server?

Comment: yes i have write permissions

Comment: Can you provide some of the code you are using? We can't tell too much of what is going on with the details you have provided so far

Comment: I have added a few things

Comment: try `df.to_sql('TableName', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)`

Comment: I have already tried, but it does not work either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250373/discussion-between-whatsthepoint-and-fabianxs).

Comment: I have read through the comments and discussion and am failing to reproduce the issue, please validate the table you mean to use exists with `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'TableName')`.